# Linux Nginx Reverse Proxy Does Not Serve Custom error.html

Tags: linux, nginx, flask, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am running nginx/1.15.7 on Ubuntu 18.04. My setup is that I have nginx serving as a reverse proxy for a Python3 Flask application. I am trying to enable a single custom error.html for all major errors ( 401, 404, 502 ... etc. ). I have tried many examples found on Google, but I am unable to have nginx serve my custom error.html when I purposefully type in an invalid URI for my nginx server. I can, however, successfully view my error.html if I visit "/error.html.

How can I make this work?

My sites-enabled configuration file is shown below:

```
server {

   # Define the server name, IP address, and/or port of the server
   listen 80;

   # Define the specified charset to the “Content-Type” response header field
   charset utf-8;

   # Specify one error page for all errors
   error_page 400 /error.html;
   error_page 401 /error.html;
   error_page 403 /error.html;
   error_page 404 /error.html;
   error_page 500 /error.html;
   error_page 503 /error.html;
   error_page 504 /error.html;

   # Create 1 error page to rule them all
   location ~ /*error.html {
        try_files error.html @error;
        internal;
   }

   location @error {
       root /var/www/localhost/html;
   }

   # Configure NGINX to deliver static content from the specified folder for main webapp
   location /main-static {
      alias /home/root/MainWebApp/static;
   }

   # Favicon
   location = /favicon.ico {

      alias /home/root/MainWebApp/static/favicon.ico;

   }

   # This is the main WebApp
   location / {

       # Define the location of the proxy server to send the request to
       proxy_pass http://comp.local.com:9000;

       # Redefine the header fields that NGINX sends to the upstream server
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_buffering off;

       # Define the maximum file size on file uploads
       client_max_body_size 5M;

   }


}
```

Comment: Nginx doesn't know if there's an error because it's passing all the urls to your backend. The backend is responsible for handling the errors. You'll have to intercept the backend error and then have nginx serve the custom response.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Please write as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Nah, that's okay. Just mark your question as duplicate of the other.